# Is there an easier way to define objects within objects?

Tags: java, class, object

so I have a class

```
public class Box {
    int index;
    static int amount;
    Box thisbox;
    Cargo thiscargo;
    Box(){
        index = amount;
        amount++;
    }
}
```

And in another class, I'll define boxes:

```
public class dostuff {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException {
        Box box = new Box();
        box.thisbox = new Box();
        box.thisbox.thisbox = new Box();
        box.thisbox.thisbox.thisbox = new Box();
        box.thisbox.thisbox.thisbox.thisbox = new Box();
    }

}
```

so as you can tell, the box.thisbox.thisbox.thisbox.thisbox gets pretty annoying. I was wondering if i could make a loop to access box.thisbox.thisbox.thisbox more easily without having to repeat the .thisbox three times. there might be a situation where I have to define 30 boxes inside of box, and I don't want to copy and paste the 'thisbox' things so many times. Would really love some help. Thanks!
Edit: I can't use array lists. dont ask...

Comment: Looks like maybe you want a LinkedList

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a recursive method that goes a certain level deep.

Something like this

```
public Box getNthBox(Box box, int depth) {
    If (depth == 0) {
        return box;
    } 

    return getNthBox(box.getBox(), depth - 1);
}
```

You need a getBox() method that returns the Box field though.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you know the termination point, i.e till when you want to keep creating the box object, you can do it in several ways. This is one of the ways to do so.

Using recursion

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Box box = new Box();
    createBox(box);
}

public static void createBox(Box box) {
        while(box.amount != 10){
        box.thisbox = new Box();
        createBox(box.thisbox);
    }
}
```